# OpenGL: won't render color (from uniform) unless printing to the console

Tags: opengl, rust, glsl, shader, uniform

Using OpenGL i've displayed a simple square with some color in it. Today I tried to set the color (actually just the green value) of it using a uniform, which contains some sort of sinus from the current time. It looks the value of the uniform is just 0.0, as it shows no green (black when setting the others colours to 0.0), **unless** I add a print statement to the loop (I can place it anywhere). If I do so, it displays a square that nicely changes in colour.

What's going on?!

This is the main source:

```
        // MAIN LOOP
        while !window.should_close() {

            // UPDATE STUFF
            let time_value = glfwGetTime();
            let green_value = ((time_value.sin() / 2.0) + 0.5) as GLfloat;
            program.set_uniform1f("uGreenValue", green_value);

            println!("yoo"); // it only works when this is somewhere in the loop 

            // RENDER STUFF
            gl::Clear(gl::COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl::DrawElements(gl::TRIANGLES, 6, gl::UNSIGNED_INT, 0 as *const GLvoid);

            window.swap_buffers();
```

This is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPosition;
layout (location = 1) in float aRedValue;
uniform float uGreenValue;

out float redValue;
out float greenValue;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
    redValue = aRedValue;
    greenValue = uGreenValue;
}
```

and this the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 Color;
in float redValue;
in float greenValue;

void main()
{
    Color = vec4(redValue, 0.0f, greenValue, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Actually you've set the blue value [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) (red-green-blue). It has to be `vec4(redValue, greenValue, 0.0f, 1.0f);`

Comment: Hahah yeah that's true. But the problem stays...

Comment: Maybe the small delay added by the `println!()` makes GL flush, can you try adding a call to `gl::Flush()` somewhere?

Comment: Nah, does not work...

Comment: I'm not seeing glfwMakeContextCurrent (or whatever the equivalent is in this language) anywhere. Without it, it's quite possible that all your GL calls are being silently ignored. (Or maybe not so silent, I don't see a glGetError() either.)
But if you print to the console, it's possible that the window manager or underlying runtime sets the window and context for you as a side effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem! In the set_uniform functions I provided a non null terminated &str to the glGetUniFormLocation function, which did not work in every occasion. Using a &cstr solved it. I still have no idea what the print statements (and other functions calls, even empty functions) had to do with it though...

Comment: This is typical for undefined behavior. Unrelated things start to influence other things. Calling a function does for example change the values below your stack pointer, but this is just guessing.